# Is it possible to discover that I used text expanders or I pasted text into a text box BEFORE sending my form?

Tags: html, security, user-interface

I work writing messages on text boxes on a NON SECURE website interface of a company. I work from my pc and google chrome with no spy programs installed because i work from home on my own pc!

They do not want people to paste messages, but there are some words that I repeat a lot and I would like to use text expanders for those words or small expression.

My question is, is it possible that the company read and saves the keys that are digited on a text box BEFORE sending them the final message that I wrote?

Example, I could create a shortcut and use GDM to write Good Morning, is it possible that the company understand that I wrote GDM instead of good morning into the text box of that I pasted a word even if the final sent message will be Good Morning and not GDM? Will they be able to record my pressed keys like CTRL C and V or GDM instead of good morning?

Comment: That would seem to require co-operation with the browser being used at the other end of a NON-SECURE website.

Comment: Sorry I did not understand, do you think it is possible even if I am in my own PC withoout any strange software installed?

Comment: Would you want any arbitrary website to be able to basically act as a key logger w/o your permission?  That's what you are describing.

Comment: Yes i would like to know if they can keylog me before I send the message, do you think it is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is possible to implement a [javascript keylogger](https://github.com/JohnHoder/Javascript-Keylogger) that logs every keystroke on that page. In your scenario the company would "benefint" from it, if they really want to detect pasting messages.

However this can be tricked by any application that calls the OS's native [function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/input-keyboard/how-to-simulate-events?view=netdesktop-6.0) that simulates the keystrokes and doesnt use keyboard shorcuts for the text expansion.

Comment: oh wow! Thanks a lot! So, do you know any application that calls the OS native function and simulates keystrokes? I would be so grateful man!

Comment: can you please help me to find such an application?